# If I install a new library, will my application still be portable?

Tags: java, javafx, portability

I am writing a macro scripting program in Java (JavaFX). I would like to add global keyboard listeners to interact with the program while it is not focused. I have heard of JNativeHook, and it looks useful. My question is, if I decide to use this library, will my code still be portable? Could I still distribute it to others without requiring them to install other things?

Comment: Yes, it is portable since all that is needed is to include the JNativeHook jars in your installation. If this weren't so, then third party libraries wouldn't be all that useful, would they?

Comment: Yes for sure it is portable

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely include native libraries in a portable app as long as your code can find the DLLs in question and you bundle them with your software.  I personally use SIGAR in portable apps and it works fine as long as the relative path remains the same, depending on how you load your DLLs.

******EDIT******

That is of course if you remain within a Windows environment and you are indeed talking about DLL files.  If you mean additional JAR files that do not require anything else than java code contained withing JAR files then yes your app will be fully portable, cross-platform too.  That is what i love about Java, i once developed a large app on Windows and it ported to Ubuntu with no modifications whatsoever.

Comment: So all I would have to do to achieve that is to include all of the necessary JAR files for JNativeHook in my project? The last thing I want is to have a program that requires special attention to be functional.

Comment: Someone posted an answer with the actual requirements of your specific library, that is the best place to look in your case, Linux has a bunch of requirements which the environment would need to fulfill for your app to work.  Other things to consider would be accessing environment-specific resources like environment variables for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your app portable if you don't need any special insulation for a different device uses different platform so in your case the library you asking for JNativeHook need some requirements mentioned here https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook#software-and-hardware-requirements. You have to give instruction to your user to have these requirements based on the platform he/she works on.